# Homepage on symfony without creating bundle and routes

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have an Apache server currently running an Api with symfony 3 I want to have a home page at the root of my domain without using symfony.

When I load `http://website.com/api/requestparameters` I can get my api request (So it's in a symfony bundle)
When I load `http://website.com/doc/` I land on a page named website.com/doc/api.html stored in `/doc/api.html` (so I dont go in the symfony thing)

but when I try to load `http://website.com` I can't reach the index.html who's located at the root of my web directory !

So I spent my whole day trying to make a bundle and create a routing so I could have my index.html in my new bundle and the routing would catch the website.com call and forward it to this bundle with my index.html.twig
I finally succeeded but I realised this is not what I want because I will have to make heavy change to my website to convert it to Twig (i have javascript and angular stuff in my index ...)

I feel like something can be done in htaccess so I tried to modify my .htaccess (linked original below)

When I set `DirectoryIndex index.html` and `RewriteEngine Off` my Api don't work anymore but my html file at the root is accessible.

When I set `DirectoryIndex index.html` and comment `RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]` same thing append

Setting `DirectoryIndex index.html` only, make no change

1. The problem is I don't want to use twig stuff.
2. I feel like bundles are not what I need and there should be another way to do it (I don't think website.com/doc/api.html use a bundle why should I use one ?)

---

**.htaccess**

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because apache redirects from root `/` to `app.php` (# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller. `RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]`)

Add rule that will rewrite root to `index.html`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]
    ...
</IfModule>
```